# Restricting app to 32bit architecture with a windows C# application

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to target a C# application to 32bit architecture, but in the platform select list, properties > build menu, there is only the 'Active (Any CPU)' option. I'm using C# 2008 Express Edition.

The app builds fine and executes without problem on 32bit, but because of a component (flash content), it fails when run on a 64 bit platform.

I'm worried that the issue is using express, from MSDN:

> "The Visual Studio Express Editions,
>   such as Visual C# Express, do not
>   support optimization for a specific
>   CPU type. This is supported only in
>   the full Visual Studio product.".

Is this even possible to do? It's not so much a question of optimisation as targetting.. ?

Comment: Pro edition has troubles too. A lot of things don't work correctly for us. Sharpdevelop is almost good enough me...

Comment: I'm right in thinking the compiler is the same in pro and express?

Comment: Yes, the compiler is the same.  If you want to compile from the command line, you can easily specify the target as x86.  It might not be possible in the Express edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use the express editions of Visual Studio very often so I'm not sure what the UI differences may be.  In a normal version of Visual Studio though you can control the targetted CPU by going to

- Right click on the project and select "Properties"
- Go to the "Build" tab
- Select x86 as the platform target

If that UI isn't available in an express edition you should be able to just manually set it in the project file.  Just open up the .csproj file and add the following line

```
<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
```

Comment: adding the tag into the csproj file - it wasn't there.